# Swift Convert Integer to 2 character Hex String

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift2

I am trying to get a two character hex value from an integer:

```
let hex = String(format:"%2X", 0)
print ("hex = \(hex)")
```

hex = "0"

How can I format String to result in always 2 characters, in this case I would want

hex = "00"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add a padding 0 before the formatter string:

```
let hex = String(format:"%02X", 0)
```

Result:

```
let hex = String(format:"%02X", 0) // 00
let hex = String(format:"%02X", 15) // 0F
let hex = String(format:"%02X", 16) // 10
```

Comment: thanks, I'm sure Apple have documented this somewhere, any links to documents would be helpful for future string manipulation.

Comment: @IanClay: This `String` method is actually bridged from the corresponding `NSString` method. The NSString documentation has a link to [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) which in turn has a link to the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) which is the ultimate reference. Easy, isn't it?